# Why is the Gogh Terminal theme not working correctly?

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

I’m running Ubuntu Gnome, and I installed the Terminal theme [Gogh](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh). However, while the background color has changed, the color of commands didn’t. Why not?

Comment: Go to preferences in the terminal, then, profiles, new and then colours. Set pallet under `built in schemes` to the theme you installed. I think this is about right, I can't check exactly because on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You can write colors configuration in `.bashrc` file. There are several places to set the colors (for example, there is `dircolors, in /usr/bin/` binary file to set the colors for dir, `setvtegb` file to set the virtual terminal colors etc.). You can also create your own `.dircolors` file in your home directory.

For the terminal, it has its own color config files. For ls, it has its own color config file, for any other component, which requires color profiles, they each have their own color config files. So, you need to dig more into it from your own operating system.

To dig more into it, do type

```
apropos "terminal colors" //apropos - search the whatis database for strings
```